# Unable to access updated state inside handleEvent function | React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using DateRangePicker to get the date ranges and append the date to the api to get the latest dates data.

As in below code i can get updated state outside the EventHandler function but not inside it. I am getting the same date which is selected for the first time.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DateRangePicker from "react-bootstrap-daterangepicker";
import "bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css";
import moment from "moment";
import DataProvider from "context/DataContext";

import ApiService from "services/api";

export default function DatePicker() {
  const [fromDate, setFromDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [toDate, setToDate] = useState(new Date());

  const range = {
    Today: [moment(), moment()],
    Yesterday: [moment().subtract(1, "days"), moment().subtract(1, "days")],
    "Last 7 Days": [moment().subtract(6, "days"), moment()],
    "Last 30 Days": [moment().subtract(29, "days"), moment()],
    "This Month": [moment().startOf("month"), moment().endOf("month")],
    "Last Month": [
      moment().subtract(1, "month").startOf("month"),
      moment().subtract(1, "month").endOf("month"),
    ],
    "Last Year": [
      moment().subtract(1, "year").startOf("year"),
      moment().subtract(1, "year").endOf("year"),
    ],
  };

  var startdate = moment(fromDate).format("yyyy-MM-DD");
  var enddate = moment(toDate).format("yyyy-MM-DD");

  console.log(startdate);

  const handleEvent = (event, picker) => {
  setFromDate(picker.startDate._d);
  setToDate(picker.endDate._d);
   
  console.log(startdate);

  var requestData = {
      metrics: ["views"],
      project_id: "abc",
      date_range: { start_at: fromDate, end_at: toDate },
    };

    ApiService.create({ requestData }).then((onSuccess) => {
      console.log(onSuccess);
    });
  };

  return (
    <DateRangePicker
      ranges={range}
      alwaysShowCalendars={false}
      onEvent={handleEvent}
    >
      <button>
        {moment(fromDate).format("ll")} to {moment(toDate).format("ll")}
      </button>
    </DateRangePicker>
  );
}
```

Comment: React state changes are asynchronous, you can't get them right after you call a set state function. If you need to react to state changes, use a `useEffect` hook for that. Otherwise, just use the values you set your state to directly if you need them right away.

Comment: @RonB. but i can't access the updated state inside the function . I can access it outside. How can i append the date to api which i want to hit right after the date change

Comment: So I told you, you can either set a `useEffect` that does that, or in your `date_range` variable in `request_data` just use the relevant values (i.e. what you're trying to set your state to) instead of the state variable itself

Comment: @RonB. thanks ... it's resolved now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In requestData object you should change fromDate to picker.startDate._d, same on the other one toDate->endDate._d

Comment: yes i can do that but i that case my calender view won't get update.

Comment: ummm ... i think you are right.. its resolved

Comment: It will be updated, just not in the moment. After you call your state out of your function, you get updated version.